# .htaccess mod_write ajax is leading to homepage

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, pagination

I have an .htacess which is now working perfectly, on this page:
   http://www.lebmotors.com/new/pror I have an ajax pagination file prorajax.php
   clicking it it gets to index.php
   $pag1->setContainerPage("http://www.lebmotors.com/new/prorajax"); This turns to an ajax link, but clicking it reached homepage index.php instead

This is the link generated by pagination class

```
    <a href='#' onclick='Submit_To_Ajax(\"$curentpage?xc=8&page=1$queriess\");'>
      &lt;&lt; </a>

 This is the ajax function:

function Submit_To_Ajax(page) 
{
  xmlHttp = AjaxHttpObject();
  if (xmlHttp==null) 
  {
    alert("Your browser does not support AJAX !!!");
    return;
  }
  else
  {
  }
  xmlHttp.open("GET", page, true);
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=StateChanged;
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}
function StateChanged() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) 
    {
        document.getElementById('AjaxDiv').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById('AjaxDiv').innerHTML='<img src="img/loading.jpg">';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED This was the reason in pagination.inc.php
href = "#" removing this resolves the issue